# Html.raw("test string") not displaying string with double quotes around it

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a string 'test string" being displayed on my html page but

`Html.Raw("test string")`

hides the string when there are double quotes around the string, so I don't see anything in the page text field

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `@Html.Raw("\"test string\"")`

Comment: `@Html.Raw("&quote;test string&quote;")`

Answer (score 3):

You must escape special characters, such as quotes, using the `\` character.

In your example it would be

```
Html.Raw("\"test string\"")
```